# How to record signal from soundcard in python

Tags: python, audio, jack, soundcard

I want to process the audio data from sound card (i.e. USB external sound card). For example: I can record all sound while playing a Youtube clip along with PC game. However, I have tried Pyaudio which only allows me to record audio from microphone. Can someone suggest me any library to try? Thanks so much!

Comment: this software: https://www.vb-audio.com/Cable/ lets you install a couple of virtual audio devices that act like a virtual cable, letting you "play" sounds into one end and record them from the other, with the added option that you can then "listen" to them through the interface you would normally use

Comment: Dear James, Does it mean I still record sound from microphone by Pyaudio, but this time, the "microphone" is virtual? For example, I create a virtual microphone which is already wired up to the sound card output. @James Kent

Comment: yes, the cable "input" is effectively an output from the pc, so you play the sound into it, the cable "output" is an audio input to the pc, so you can use pyaudio to record from it, with the added benefit that you can set it up to also come out the real output. effectively allowing you to record whatever you're listening to.

Comment: @JamesKent, I have tried some library for this purpose in python. I found Pyjack really look promising. However, I couldn't find the exact way to direct the sound output from PC to be "input". Do you have suggestion for that? It is because I don't want to use software to create the cable.